# How do I compare two different numeric variables and changing one variable if one the first variable is greater than the second? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, numeric

An example:
If A = 5
And b = 6
If 2 is added to A,
I want A and b to = 7.

I want B to change only when A is greater than B and then I want B to copy the same number as A.

I hope this explains what i am looking, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Math.max(...):

```
var a:Number = 5;
var b:Number = 6;
a = a + 2;
b = Math.max(a, b);
```

b will become equal to the higher value of a (5+2) or b (6) - in this case 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Suppose A is already 5, and b is already 6.
A += 2
if (A > b) b = A
```

Hope this helps :)